# Is statement is entire or not entire?

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

Is the following statement is correct or incorrect ?

let $f\colon\mathbb{C} \longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be a function

[image]

my try : this statement is true because  here partial derivative exist  and its satisfied the cauchy riemann equation...so it will be analytics that mean it will be entire.

Is my answer is correct or incorrect ,,pliz verified and tell me the solution i would be more thankful...

Comment: Where do you see that the function satisfies Cauchy-Riemann equation?

Comment: @edm..here partial derivative is exist,,so cauchy reimann satisfied..as Ux =Vy

Comment: @Jameslegolegoh That is not mentioned in the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not true. Take, for instance, $f(z)=\operatorname{Re}(z)$. So, $f_1(x,y)=x$ and $f_2(x,y)=0$. The function $f$ is not differentiable.

Comment: @ jose carlos santos according to ur answer.....dfi/dx = 1 and df /dy = 0....how can u say that f is not differntiable?

Comment: @Jameslegolegoh An entire function if a complex differentiable function. In particular, its real and imaginary parts must satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations. The real and imaginary parts of the function that I provided don't satisfy those equations.

Comment: thanks ..got it @ Jose carlos santos